# persian references with multibib package

Tags: multibib, xepersian

We have used the `multibib` package with `\newcites{ب}` command.

Because this letter "ب" is one of the Persian  letters, latex makes `.aux` file with the strange and undefined name and its variable in any computer (like `ظ..aux`). So we can't write unique commands to build our reference.
Like `bibtex A.aux`.

How can I solve this problem?

We want latex show ‍‍`[الف1]` in output pdf.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}
\newcommand{\ReferenceDocuments}{\rl{مستندات مرجع}}
\newcommand{\RelevantDocumentation}{\rl{مستندات ذیربط}}
\newcites{الف,ب}{\ReferenceDocuments%
,
\RelevantDocumentation}
\begin{document}
یک استناد به مستندات مرجع
 \cite{bb} 
 یک استناد به مستندات ذیربط
  \citeالف{aa}
  یک استناد به مراجع اصلی
 \citeالف{cc}
 یک استناد دیگر 
 \citeب{dd}

\renewcommand{\refname}{\rl{مراجع}}
\bibliographystyle{plain-fa}
\bibliography{lit}                 

\bibliographystyleالف{plain}
\bibliographyالف{lit}         

\bibliographystyleب{plain}
\bibliographyب{lit}          

\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@Article{aa,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2000
}

@ARTICLE{bb,
  AUTHOR =  {واحدی, مصطفی},
  TITLE =  {درختان پوشای کمینه دورنگی مسطح},
  JOURNAL =  {مجله فارسی نمونه},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1387},
  NUMBER =  {2},
  MONTH =  {آبان},
  PAGES =  {22-30},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian}
}

@ARTICLE{dd,
  AUTHOR =  {بهبودی‌فام, حسین},
  TITLE =  {یک عنوان درست و درمون},
  JOURNAL =  {مجله فارسی نمونه},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1387},
  NUMBER =  {2},
  MONTH =  {آبان},
  PAGES =  {22-30},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian}
}

@ARTICLE{cc,
  AUTHOR =  {بهبودی, احمد},
  TITLE =  {یک عنوان درست و درمون},
  JOURNAL =  {مجله فارسی نمونه},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1387},
  NUMBER =  {2},
  MONTH =  {آبان},
  PAGES =  {22-30},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian}
}
```

Output pdf:
[image]

Comment: What you could try is copy ب.aux to A.aux, then run `bibtex A`, then copy A.bbl to ب.bbl, and the same for the other one. I tried this on my Mac and it worked. I don't know any Persian, so I cannot check if the output is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Your idea is correct. Even running ب.aux is correct but my goal is to have a true file name. Because in every computer it makes .aux file with a variable name so we can not use unique commands to build.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Because on my Mac I can just run  `bibtex ب.aux` and `bibtex  الف.aux` without problems.

Comment: I have windows with texlive 2016.Can you say me what is the file name that built with xelatex main? Is it الف.aux or ظ..aux and other like this?

Comment: The files I get are `الف.aux` and `ب.aux`. MacOS uses utf-8 for file names, while Windows uses utf-16, if I am correct. Maybe that makes a difference. Because your document probably is in utf-8, which is the default for xelatex and lualatex. I compiled with xelatex.

Comment: Is there any way to force windows to use utf-8?

Comment: If you run bibtex from the command line, you can try: `set COMMAND_LINE_ENCODING=utf8` and then run bibtex. Maybe that works.